# I want to get the current weather update of my current location

Tags: android, weather, forecasting

i want to get the current weather update of my current location in android.
the weather update may b in C or F.
i dnt want any extended forecast values...
flow of my app is like:
it gets coodinates and from the coordinates it gets name of the location..based on that location it must return me the weather condition of that area.
kindly help me out in completing this module. m new to android :)
if possible plz give me code sample.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: A bit like this app does? https://market.android.com/details?id=de.devmil.minimaltext&hl=en http://www.appbrain.com/app/minimalistic-text/de.devmil.minimaltext

Comment: There is nothing in android that gives you weather forecasts. you'll have to extract the information from a remote server and show it in your application.

Comment: @Umesh.... how can i do that??   i need a sample code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to get that, mostly web services but you need to check the terms of service, a lot of them don't want you to embed them in a paying app

[via Weather Underground and others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180388/programatically-access-weather-info) [via Msn and Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951839/api-to-get-weather-based-on-longitude-and-latitude-coordinates) [National Weather Service REST](http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/rest.php)

You probably just want to search for "[Android] Weather" in SO search bar and find something that fits.  Googles Weather API seems to be the easiest [Google Weather API Tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/android_weather_forecast_-_google_weather_api_-_description-t337.html)

Comment: google weather api is not working anymore , it demand self authentication

Comment: @Houcine yeah they turned it off, though if you set the referrer to google calendar it will still work (for how long who knows) https://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=23220&hl=en&referrer=googlecalendar

Comment: +1 for the googlecalendar referrer, i'm using MSN weather API for now :).

Comment: @Houcine I was going to look at that as well, did you find any doc's on the subject, specifically hourly vs. current and projected by day?

Comment: @ldistic : i didn't find any official docs about it , i've just used informations from stackoverflow  threads about that. and i've developed a demo for it .